# CORS - why is Access-control-allow-origin header necessary?

Tags: http, cross-domain

Premise:

When an site (http://example.com) tries to make a cross-origin request, the browser will send an HTTP request to the cross-origin server (http://other-server.com) with the header `Origin: http://example.com`. If the server at http://other-server.com approves http://example.com as a valid origin, then it will 1) Respond without error AND 2) set the response header to `Access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com`

My question is - why is it necessary to set the `Access-control-allow-origin` header in the response? Doesn't responding without error already acknowledge that the server (http://other-server.com) is allowing the cross-origin request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extra layer of acknowledgement gives servers a lot of flexibility over how they support CORS. For example:

1) A server has a lot of choices when setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It can use the `*` value to allow all clients, or it can limit the scope of clients by using the actual value of the origin (e.g. `http://example.com`). If a server does support CORS, but not for all origins, it could respond without error, but the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` could be set to `http://notyourorigin.com`.

2) CORS allows even more flexibility via the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` preflight response headers. These headers go beyond the simple binary success/error HTTP status, and provide more nuanced information about what is and is not supported in the server.

As the examples above point out, an error response without any context can be very confusing to the user. If you make a CORS request, and all you get back is an error response, you have no idea why that request failed. Are you doing the request wrong? Does the server support CORS at all? This can be very difficult to figure out without any accompanying information. The `Access-Control-*` gives more context to the user so they can effectively debug their CORS requests.